# Regular Expression won't show up as complete string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use [this regular expression](http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=1121) in my application, but for some reason C# won't accept it as a complete string.

If I'm not mistaken, it has to do with a couple of double quotes in the expression, but it looks to me like they're escaped.

Here's the RegEx:

`^((([hH][tT][tT][pP][sS]?|[fF][tT][pP])\:\/\/)?([\w\.\-]+(\:[\w\.\&%\$\-]+)*@)?((([^\s\(\)\<\>\\\"\.\[\]\,@;:]+)(\.[^\s\(\)\<\>\\\"\.\[\]\,@;:]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))|((([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(\b\:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)\b)?((\/[^\/][\w\.\,\?\'\\\/\+&%\$#\=~_\-@]*)*[^\.\,\?\"\'\(\)\[\]!;<>{}\s\x7F-\xFF])?)$`

And here's how I'm trying to declare it:

`[RegularExpression(@"^((([hH][tT][tT][pP][sS]?|[fF][tT][pP])\:\/\/)?([\w\.\-]+(\:[\w\.\&%\$\-]+)*@)?((([^\s\(\)\<\>\\\"\.\[\]\,@;:]+)(\.[^\s\(\)\<\>\\\"\.\[\]\,@;:]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))|((([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(\b\:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)\b)?((\/[^\/][\w\.\,\?\'\\\/\+&%\$#\=~_\-@]*)*[^\.\,\?\"\'\(\)\[\]!;<>{}\s\x7F-\xFF])?)$")]`

Sorry about the formatting, I cannot figure out how to display it best...

To reiterate, C# does not recognize it as a string when placed in double quotes.

How can I use this expression in C#?

Comment: Please show how you are declaring this string in your code, that's the important part.

Comment: Use binary elimination. Remove half (add or remove parens as necessary) and see if it works.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Added some code, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a string literal with `@` and double up your double quotes like`@"a ""b"" c"`

Comment: Doubling up my double quotes fixed it, thanks. Will accept as answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape twice.  once for the `\` and once for your regex.

each escape sequence should be

`\\d`

alternatively

Comment: No; use a verbatim string literal.

Comment: @SamIam To escape quotes in a verbatim string literal one would repeat the quotes twice.